# Random only one time for check two array correspondence

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
actPosX = [300 ,330, 360];
actPosY = [300 ,300 ,300];
```

and I would like generate only one time two random number

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random()*20)*30 
y = Math.floor(Math.random()*20)*30
```

and I want this two numbers are not in the same position in both arrays

```
Column 1     Column 2     column 3
-----------------------------------
  300         330           360       
  300         300           300
```

Also the only one time generated numbers can not be "300 300" or "330 300" or "360 300".

Is an example, my arrays contain a lot of data.

Comment: So you only want values existing in the two arrays respectively?  It's unclear to me how the two arrays relate to each other.

Comment: No any of them. Just not the same of each colum on two array.

Comment: Not clear enough..

Comment: If x generates as `330` must the value of y be `300`?

Comment: Also i would like random number who are not "300 300", "330 300" or "360 300"

Comment: You'd just do an indexOf on each number on their respective arrays. If the indexes are the same then the column is the same.

Comment: Ok, so you want two numbers who are not in the same position in both arrays.

Comment: @Taplar exactly :-)

Comment: You cannot perform a one time random generation without the possibility of a collision.  You have to handle for the possible collision.  The only way around this is to have arrays with every possible result left and to randomly generate an index of the array for a combination not used yet, after which removing it from the possibilities so it will no longer be pickable.

Comment: Yes @Taplar i have make this but is very durty. Ok But if you say is not possible. Thanks

Comment: What is the valid range of values?  1-600?

Comment: 0 to 600 step 30

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```js
var possibilities = [];

//create all possibilities
for (var i = 0; i <= 600; i += 30){
  for (var j = 0; j <= 600; j+= 30) {
    possibilities.push({ x: i, y: j });
  }
}

var actPosX = [300 ,330, 360];
var actPosY = [300 ,300 ,300];

//remove the possibilities already used
actPosX.forEach(function(x, index){
  var possibility = possibilities.find(function(element){
    return (element.x === x && element.y === actPosY[index]);
  });
  
  possibilities.splice(possibilities.indexOf(possibility), 1);
});

//now find a possibility not used yet
var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * possibilities.length * 10) % possibilities.length);

console.log('X: ', possibilities[index].x, ', Y: ', possibilities[index].y);

//put the used possibility in your array
actPosX.push(possibilities[index].x);
actPosY.push(possibilities[index].y);

//remove the possibility
possibilities.splice(index, 1);

//now you're ready to repeat the random logic for your next possibility
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution regenerate a number on loop. And if only one case remains, it will take hours

Comment: What do you mean only one case remains?

Comment: Example: actPosX  contain all of value possible exept one. you solution generate and generate until found the last value

Comment: Ok i will clarify

Comment: Ok i have clarify :-)

Answer (score -1):

You would just need to check the index of each number on its respective array. If the indexes are the same then the numbers are on the same "column". Here is a way you could accomplish this.

```
actPosX = [300 ,330, 360];
actPosY = [300 ,300 ,300];

function isSameColumn(x, y)
{
    return actPosX.indexOf(x) === actPosY.indexOf(y);
}

isSameColumn(300, 300);
isSameColumn(300, 360);
```

Comment: This is not a problem. I would like generate a random number. With this solution, if the number exist, i have to regenerate one. But i dont want generate and regenerate...